# Join query - avoid "SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1" and timeouts

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got two mysql tables:

Table1 (80K+ products):

```
_products

product_id         status          ean          category
```

Table 2: (700K+ product attributes, matched on table one on column "ean")

```
 _productinformation

 info_id        ean       info_group         info_type         info_value
```

My challenge:

I want to select 30 products out of the "products" table (based on their status and category) and match those products on the column ean with the other table. Next, I want to filter out of the matches in the "productinformation" table for which the ean is the same as the ones selected in "products" and column "info_type" matches a specific value. The following SQL does almost what I want, except two issues:

1. SQL BIG QUERIES needs to be used (which makes the query extremely slow up to 5 minutes)
2. The query returns not just one row with the ean and the selected rows for info_type, but returns 40+ rows with 40+ times exactly the same info per ean (I think that is the total number of rows with that specific ean code in table "productinformation").

The query I constructed:

```
SELECT    _products.ean
        , _products.status
        , product_brand.info_value as product_brand
        , product_type.info_value as product_type
        , product_price.info_value as product_price
    FROM _products
    LEFT JOIN _productinformation ON _products.ean = _productinformation.ean
    LEFT JOIN _productinformation as product_brand ON _products.ean = product_brand.ean
    LEFT JOIN _productinformation as product_type ON _products.ean = product_type.ean
    LEFT JOIN _productinformation as product_price ON _products.ean = product_price.ean
    WHERE product_brand.info_type = 'brand'
        AND product_type.info_type = 'type'
        AND product_price.info_type = 'price'
        AND  _products.category='1'
```

This returns something like (40+ rows with the same product):

```
     ean            status     product_brand     product_type     product_price
     0123456789     1          brand1            type1            0.00
     0123456789     1          brand1            type1            0.00
     0123456789     1          brand1            type1            0.00
     0123456789     1          brand1            type1            0.00
     0123456789     1          brand1            type1            0.00
     etc.
```

However, I'd like to see 30 different products:

```
     ean            status     product_brand     product_type     product_price
     0123456789     1          brand1            type1            0.00
     9876543210     3          brand6            type3            15.00
     6548214656     45         brand34           type1            99.00 
     245511411241   4          brand324          type1            98.00
     etc.
```

Is there someone who can tell me if the query I am looking for is possible? And how should it look like? I have already tried 100+ different queries (3 days further...), but all failed. The query above came most close.
Hope someone could help me out! Thnx!

Comment: Are you sure this is properly indexed for the types of queries you're doing? `EXPLAIN` can help debug indexing problems.

Comment: You join to `_productinformation` 4 times, yet are only looking for three pieces of information. Your first join to `_productinformation` (the one with no alias) is redundant and the reason for your duplication.

Comment: Looks like the tables are not indexed correctly: (rows: 44634 and for the second: rows: 1068368). I am not familiar with indexes and started reading about it. How would you advise to index the tables? Which indexes on which columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will us the following tables for examples to explain this answer. They are similar to yours except I left out a few fields that don't seem to come into play in this query.

```
#Products
+ ---------- + ------ + ------------ +
| Product_Id | Status | EAN          |
+ ---------- + ------ + ------------ +
| 1          | 1      | 0123456789   |
| 2          | 3      | 9876543210   |
| 3          | 45     | 6548214656   |
| 4          | 4      | 245511411241 |
+ ---------- + ------ + ------------ +

#Info
+ ------- + ------------ + --------- + ---------- +
| Info_Id | EAN          | Info_Type | Info_Value |
+ ------- + ------------ + --------- + ---------- +
| 1       | 0123456789   | brand     | brand1     |
| 2       | 0123456789   | type      | type1      |
| 3       | 0123456789   | price     | 0.00       |
| 4       | 9876543210   | brand     | brand6     |
| 5       | 9876543210   | type      | type3      |
| 6       | 9876543210   | price     | 15.00      |
| 7       | 6548214656   | brand     | brand34    |
| 8       | 6548214656   | type      | type1      |
| 9       | 6548214656   | price     | 99.00      |
| 10      | 245511411241 | brand     | brand324   |
| 11      | 245511411241 | type      | type1      |
| 12      | 245511411241 | price     | 98.00      |
+ ------- + ------------ + --------- + ---------- +
```

Now consider the following query

```
select    i.EAN
        , p.ProductStatus
        , case info_type when 'brand' then info_value end as brand
        , case info_type when 'type' then info_value end as [type]
        , case info_type when 'price' then info_value end as price
    from #Info i
    inner join #Products p on p.ean = i.ean
```

which produces a table like

```
+ ------------ + ------ + -------- + ----- + ----- +
| EAN          | status | brand    | type  | price |
+ ------------ + ------ + -------- + ----- + ----- +
| 0123456789   | 1      | brand1   | NULL  | NULL  |
| 0123456789   | 1      | NULL     | type1 | NULL  |
| 0123456789   | 1      | NULL     | NULL  | 0.00  |
| 9876543210   | 3      | brand6   | NULL  | NULL  |
| 9876543210   | 3      | NULL     | type3 | NULL  |
| 9876543210   | 3      | NULL     | NULL  | 15.00 |
| 6548214656   | 45     | brand34  | NULL  | NULL  |
| 6548214656   | 45     | NULL     | type1 | NULL  |
| 6548214656   | 45     | NULL     | NULL  | 99.00 | 
| 245511411241 | 4      | brand324 | NULL  | NULL  |
| 245511411241 | 4      | NULL     | type1 | NULL  |
| 245511411241 | 4      | NULL     | NULL  | 98.00 |
+ ------------ + ------ + -------- + ----- + ----- +
```

As you can see, I only use a single join with some case statements in the selection portion to create the columns I want. This has a huge advantage over using multiple joins because none of the records are duplicated.

To finish up, a simple aggregation will give us what we want

```
select    i.EAN
        , p.ProductStatus
        , max(case info_type when 'brand' then info_value end) as brand
        , max(case info_type when 'type' then info_value end) as [type]
        , max(case info_type when 'price' then info_value end) as price
    from #Info i
    inner join #Products p on p.ean = i.ean
    group by i.EAN, p.ProductStatus

+ ------------ + ------ + -------- + ----- + ----- +
| EAN          | Status | brand    | type  | price |     
+ ------------ + ------ + -------- + ----- + ----- +
| 0123456789   | 1      | brand1   | type1 | 0.00  |
| 245511411241 | 4      | brand324 | type1 | 98.00 |
| 6548214656   | 45     | brand34  | type1 | 99.00 |
| 9876543210   | 3      | brand6   | type3 | 15.00 |
+ ------------ + ------ + -------- + ----- + ----- +
```

You can then use a CTE to filter specific fields of this table, like so (**SQL Server Only**):

```
; with
    CTE as (
        select    i.EAN
                , p.ProductStatus
                , max(case info_type when 'brand' then info_value end) as brand
                , max(case info_type when 'type' then info_value end) as [type]
                , max(case info_type when 'price' then info_value end) as price
            from #Info i
            inner join #Products p on p.ean = i.ean
            group by i.EAN, p.ProductStatus
    )
select *
    from CTE
    where price >= 99 -- or whatever other filter you want
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I will try this later this week! In addition: indexes are still a wise advice to speed up the queries, right?

Comment: @mh3982 indices are always a good idea... as long as you don't overdo it ;)

Comment: perfect solution, this works great! I've also implemented some indexes. Right now, the only of the columns above that does not have an index is: "Info_Value". Would someone suggest doing the indexes differently?

Comment: One additional question: Suppose I want to only select the joins where: 
Info_Type=price and for those rows: Info_Value>99. Besides I want to only select specific values for brand (Info_Type=brand and Info_Value="specific brand"). In other words, filter on specific information values. How do I add that to this specific query?

Comment: @mh3982 If you were using SQL Server, I would recommend doing this with a CTE. However, I don't know if MySQL supports CTE's, and if it does, I don't know the syntax for them. You should ask this additional question as a new question and see if anyone can help you. In the meantime, if you feel that my answer is sufficient for the question you originally posted, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Unfortunately I dont see your last response at the answere. I only see:     "You can then use a CTE to filter specific fields of this table, like so:

Hope this helps!" 

Like how? :) Unfortunately, the sample code is missing. @KindaTechy

Comment: @mh3982 I updated the answer to include the CTE part. But again, it's written specifically for SQL Server, not for MySQL